# M2 - Create own CMS page template

Tags: magento2, custom, page

I want to create my own custom template to choose from a CMS page in Magento 2.

I've already done the following:

**Created bktext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="2columns-left"/>
</layout>
```

**And also layouts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page_layouts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/PageLayout/etc/layouts.xsd">
<layout id="bktext">
    <label translate="true">New text - Page</label>
</layout>
</page_layouts>
```

So the page is now visible from the dropdown.

But how can I now make my own design with the normal HTML markup? Just like the old version of Magento where I could edit the .phtml file with just divs and other normal markup.

Is that even possible?

Regards,

Edit:

I just want to make up a file like this:

```
<header>Header content with menu</header
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            Content from the CMS page
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 sidebar">
            <ul>
                <li>Text</li>
                <li>Text</li>
                <li>Text</li>
                <li>Text</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<footer>Footer content</footer>
```

Is that possible? Instead of using the blocks where I have no idea to edit the files?

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your question is You want to create a template file and want to use through cms from back end. If it is not this in your need please ignore it.

- First of all you can create a cms page from back end and call directly the template file in to that cms content like

example

> {{block class="Magento\Bannerslider\Block\Slideshow" template="Magento_Bannerslider::bannerslider.phtml"}}

Or if you are trying to create new custom theme for your new project just follow the  below link.

[Magento2 Custom theme](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html)

[for custom theme](https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/3171-2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try below step to create the custom layout.

Create Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layouts.xml this file for the custom layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page_layouts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/PageLayout/etc/layouts.xsd">
    <layout id="mylayout">
        <label translate="true">my layout</label>
    </layout>
</page_layouts>
```

2- Use the layout in this custom layout. Vendor/Module/view/frontend/mylayout.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="1column"/>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

Comment: Hi Birjitsinh, Thanks for the answer, but how can I make my custom block to load with my own content? I've updated my answer also with what I exactly mean.